# ES 6.2 Filter nested objects out of list

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm not sure if this is possible or if there is a better way to structure my documents.

My current mapping structure looks like:

```
{
"objectName": {
    "person": {
        "properties": {
             "firstName": {
                 "type": "text"
              }
         }
    }
    "properties": {
        "id": {
            "type": "long"
        },
        "sections": {
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "title": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "sectionDetails": {
                    "type" : "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "id": {
                            "type": "long"
                        }
                        "detail": {
                            "properties": {
                                "id": {
                                    "type": "long"
                                },
                                "type": {
                                    "type": "keyword"
                                },
                                "value": {
                                    "type": "long"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(I've changed the names of objects and slimmed down the properties to make it more stackoverflow friendly)

What i want to be able to do is to get an avg of all "section.sectionDetail.detail.value" where the type is "typeOne".

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "grades_stats": {
      "filter": {
        "fuzzy": {
          "person.firstName": "m"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "agg1_name": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "sections.sectionDetails"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "grades_stats": {
              "filter": {
                "term": {
                  "sections.sectionDetails.details.type": "rating"
                }
              },
              "aggs": {
                "avg_ratomg": {
                  "avg": {
                    "field": "sections.sectionDetails.details.value"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, a document can have many "sections" and many "sectionDetails".
Currently if i use a bool filter and say where type "must_not"  "typeTwo", then i loose any documents that has any "typeTwo"s (which may also contain some "typeOne"s which i wanted in my avg

Any thaughts on how i can structure this better?

Edit:
I've updated the structure and query to match the latest progress.
When i query, i get a value of null. i belive the filters are incorrect

Comment: In order to achieve what you want, `sections` and `sectionDetails` need to be of type `nested`

Comment: @Val I've made that change, however whenever i query now, it looks like it's returning the entire document (with siblings)
For example. If i query for           "sections.sectionDetails.details.type" : "typeTwo" i'm still getting the full document, which includes "typeOne" results

Comment: You also need to use [`nested inner_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html#nested-inner-hits)

Comment: @Val Thanks for your help so far. I've updated the question with the latest structure and query that i'm using. However, it is returning null as a result. Can you just confirm that the query seems correct?
I'm trying to get an aggregate of all detail.value and filter by detail.type and person.name